# How to auto associate Microsoft Office extensions to Libre Office

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office

How to auto associate Microsoft Office extensions to Libre Office. so that if we open a docx file it automatically uses the Libre Office Writer.

Comment: Can you just right click the file, select 'open with..' and check the 'use as default application' and select Libre Office?

Comment: yes, but i don't find libreoffice

Comment: Hm.  When I get home I'll see if I can figure it out.  I'm at work until 00:00 GMT, so don't expect a response from me for at least 5/6 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click on the document, and choose Open With LibreOffice Writer.

[image]

If not listed, click on Open With Other Application, and then choose LibreOffice Writer.

[image]

Or right click on the file, choose Properties, and then click on Open With, choose Libreoffice Writer, and then click Set as Default.

[image]

I would recommend that you completly remove LibreOffice, and re-install it.
To remove:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To Install the latest:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: but for me "set as default" is disabled for the Microsoft word document and unable to open with first two steps. Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of LibreOffice are you running?

Comment: at now i found that libreoffice was not working. i think this may be the reason, i tried this command 


sudo apt-get install python-software-properties 


sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0


sudo apt-get update


sudo apt-get upgrade


please help me in getting the libreoffice work again

Comment: See the addition in my answer.

Comment: Thanks@Mitch it resolved my problem as well as it upgraded my libreoffice version, i have voted up

Comment: still "set as default" is disabled for the Microsoft word document

Comment: Any chance you can add an image?

Comment: It is similar to your last image which you have added (pxe.docx properties)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9979/discussion-between-mitch-and-blue)